# least sold product in the array

Tags: arrays

You are given n products that were sold by a shopkeeper on a particular day. Each product is represented by a unique id.

We are given the list of the unique ids of the products that were sold that day in an array prod.

Find the product that was sold the least.

Note

If there are two or more products that are sold the least then return the product with smaller unique id.

Input Format
Input consists of two lines.

First line contains an integer n which is the size of the prod array.

Next line contains n spaced integers which shows the unique ids.

Output Format
Return the least sold product.

Example 1
Input

6
1 4 1 3 1 4
Output

3
Explanation

Here the product with unique id 3 is sold 1 time which is less than any other product.

Example 2
Input

5
1 2 3 4 5
Output

1

answer expected not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

This is written in javascript but the principle should work in any language;

```
function getLeastSoldProduct(input){
    var smallestNum = Number.MAX_VALUE;  
    var id = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(smallestNum > input[i]){
            smallestNum = input[i];
            id = i;
        }
    }
    return id;
}

getLeastSoldProduct([6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4]);
```